# Where should I ask questions?

Tags: discussion, soft-question

I am a sophomore student in China, and I have already learned all the undergraduate courses and several graduate courses in my college. Now I am trying to solve out the problems in qualify exam of some American universities. I want to know where can I discuss such problems with others?

Comment: Do you want to know where you can find qualifying exam questions, or given such questions, where you can get help with them?